# Google adwords tracking code

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help? I have button in js file, and I must put analytics code into button but I get `Unexpected identifier` error:

Button code

```
function show_iwantknow() {
    html = "<div class='block-Form'><form name='IWK'><div class='input'><div class='icon person'></div><input type='text' name='name' id='nameIWK' placeholder='Введите ваше имя'></div><div class='input'><div class='icon phone'></div><input type='text' name='mobile' id='mobileIWK' placeholder='Введите ваш телефон'></div><div class='input'><div class='icon email'></div><input type='email' name='email' id='emailIWK' placeholder='Введите ваш email'></div><input type='button' value='Хочу узнать!' id='sendIWK' onClick="
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/virtual/podtverdit']);
    _gaq.push['_trackEvent', 'Knopka', 'Podtverdit']);
"></form></div>";
$("#w_content").html(html);
}
```

Google code:

```
onClick = "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/virtual/podtverdit']); _gaq.push['_trackEvent','Knopka','Podtverdit']);"
```

Comment: Improved readability

Comment: Well, if you look at the syntax highlighting it's pretty clear that you are breaking your string (by inserting `"` in the middle of it, eg.: `onCick="`)

Comment: Code looks like truncated.

Comment: This code from google https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq , onClick = "_ is right